# SQL Insert does column order matter

Tags: sql-server, schema

I have two tables with the same field names and a stored procedure that updates table B with Table A's data by doing a delete from current table and insert into current table from another table that has update values in it:

```
delete from ac.Table1

insert into ac.Table1
    select *
    from  dbo.OriginalTable
    where dtcreate <getdate()-1
```

I had to recreate Table1 through GIS software which adds GlobalIDs and an Object ID field. The original order had Object ID at the end and the new table has it at the front. Will this impact executing the SQL statement above?

Comment: Best practice is to always explicitly list the columns being inserted into and selected from. That way you will never get any surprises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it will. The order of the columns should match for each value to go in desired column
You can try
Insert into ac.Table1 (column1....columnN)